# Deploying Salesforce Profile via Git

Tags: deployment, profile, git, github

Has anyone successfully deployed Profiles using Git? If yes, what are the steps to do that?

I tried to find documentation, but have not been able to find anything that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is how Profile deployments work. Profile definitions are massive so instead of deploying the entire profile every time it's moved org to org, salesforce only brings over the system level permissions. FLS and other object/field permissions are included when the associated metadata is included in the package being deployed.

If you are trying to deploy changes only to system level profile permissions, that is doable pretty easily through git. However, if you need other object security items, things become more challenging as you need to include them in the retrieve/deploy process.

Products like Copado help with Profile deployments. This article is a little heavy on the marketing side but it has some good content on [Profile deployments](https://docs.essentials.copado.com/en/articles/4109815-deploy-profiles).

Comment: Rory - Thank you for that info. That is exactly what I have found so far. I do know that products like Copado, Gearset, etc, help with Profile deployments. I was wondering if there is a way to deploy profiles with using only Github.